# How to create a Layout with React

Tags: html, reactjs, layout, header

```
// components/Layout/Layout.tsx
const Layout = () => {
  return (
    <div>

    </div>
  )
}

export default Layout

// components/Layout/Header/Header.tsx
const Header = () => {
  return (
    <header>
      <h2>This is Header</h2>
    </header>
  )
}

export default Header

// components/Layout/Footer/Footer.tsx
const Footer = () => {
  return (
    <footer>
      <h2>This is Footer</h2>
    </footer>
  )
}

export default Footer

// pages/index.tsx
import Layout from "../components/Layout/Layout"
import HomeContainer from "../containers/Home/HomeContainer"

const HomePage = () => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <HomeContainer />
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default HomePage
```

I am making a simple webpage with React. This time, I am trying to write with the HTML structure in mind, but I have a difficult question.

How to implement a page that should not have other headers or footers when the page is rendered by creating a layout component and wrapping it with a route?

※Additional question: Is it possible to create a mobile responsive web by using useMediaQuery in the Layout component?

Answer (score 2):

You need render the children prop in Layout component.

```
const Layout = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <header>Header</header>
      { props.children }
      <footer>Footer</footer>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to render the children inside the `div`. `Layout` component syntax will be like:

```js
// components/Layout/Layout.tsx
const Layout = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Layout;
```

Using Layout component

```js
const AnyPage = () => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      \* Children written here will render inside your div of Layout component *\
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default AnyPage;
```

Home page with Header and footer will be like

```js
// pages/index.tsx
import Layout from "../components/Layout/Layout"
//import Header and Footer here

const HomePage = () => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Header />
      {Additional components or HTML code here}
      <Footer />
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default HomePage;
```

※Additional: Yes, you can add a CSS class for the `div` of `Layout` component to make it responsive.

```js
// components/Layout/Layout.tsx

//import style sheet here

const Layout = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <div className="class-to-make-responsive">
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Layout;
```